# Can all string matching tasks be accomplished by only using the most basic syntax of regular expressions?

Tags: regex, string, text, string-matching, python-re

By 'basic', I mean not using **these** regex syntax / features:

- *non-capturing groups*  **(?:pattern)**
- *look ahead positive assert*  **(?=pattern)**
- *negative assert*  **(?!pattern)**
- *look behind*  **(?<=pattern)**
- ... and so on

If I **only** use "capturing groups" along with those meta-characters (e.g. `\s`, `\d`), can I get all the job done?

Comment: Probably not. These features were added to regular expressions to solve problems.

Comment: However, non-capturing groups are not necessary, they just make things more efficient (if all groups are capturing, you simply ignore the ones you don't need).

Comment: It depends what you mean by "get all the job done". Suppose you want to know if a given string contains all the letters `'a'`, `'b'` , `'c'` and  `'d'`.  You can answer that with four positive lookaheads: `^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)`. Without using positive lookaheads you must use an alternation with 4! = 24 parts, `.*a.*b.*c.*d|.*a.*b.*d.*c|..` While this can be shortened with more complex logic (e.g., `.*a.*b.*(?:c.*d|d,*c)|...`), suppose it was desired to...

Comment: ...determine if the string contained at least two of each of those four letters. We could write `^(?=.*a.*a)(?=.*b.*b)(?=.*c.*c)(?=.*d.*d)`. Now the corresponding alternation has 8!/(2^4) parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we wish to match a string that begins `'dog'` and ends `'cat'` that does not contain `'pig'`. We can do that with a regular expression that employs the [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) technique, which employs a negative lookahead:

```
dog(?:(?!pig).)*cat
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YX8lsc/1).

While it is a logical impossibility to prove that this task cannot be done with a regular expression that does not contain a lookaround, I am not aware of such an expression. Readers are invited to suggest one that does.

---

This regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
dog      # match 'dog'
(?:      # begin a non-capture group
  (?!    # begin a negative lookahead
    pig  # match 'pig'
  )      # end the negative lookahead
  .      # match any character other than a line terminator
)        # end the non-capture group
*        # execute the preceding non-capture group zero or more times
cat      # match 'cat'
```

---

Come to think of it, one could use an alternation with all permutations of all numbers (up to the the string size less 6) of all permissible characters that forms a string that does not contain `'pig'`: `dogcat|dogacat|dogbcat| ... |dogaabcat|dogabacat| ... |dogaZrnpiht0xcat|...` but with longer strings this could be somewhat demanding computationally.